# Why does JMeter HTTP Response differ from the browser response?

Tags: jmeter

I have a magic link to access a website without logging in, let's say the magic link is something like this

```
https://key.example.exampl.tr/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=my-react-client&state=ba453a80-d991-4b3b-a791-3fc2629aea03&redirect_uri=https://test.example.exampl.tr/&scope=openid&response_type=code&user_id=d0bcdd07-3198-4ab6-9cfd-d0b6341dbe00&key=7a1b4163-76e8-465c-a914-c68f16761698
```

when I use the link in the browser it works as expected and accesses the home page without asking me to log in. BUT when I use the same link inside HTTP GET Request using JMeter, it redirects me to the login page. Why is that happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening as you browser stores specific cookies and caches for the particular request, whereas for jmeter you will request a new session every time, if you are not using HTTP Cookie Manager and HTTP Cache Manager explicitly.

Try clearing your browser history, cookies & caches  and hit the same request/url, it would also redriect to the login page and behave same as jmeter does

Comment: No this is not happening, I tried the scenario above on the browser after clearing everything and the link is working correctly without logging in

Comment: Have you tried across different browsers? Also, have you tried with other tools like Postman to create the request and is it's behavior comparable with JMeter or browser? As @Angshuman Basak it could be an issue of cookies and cache being retained or the session still persisting (I suspect session persist as well because your URL has state parameter)